# Postgres: Avoid ROLLBACK on UPDATE exception

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to run an `UPDATE` command on 7 million rows.  The `UPDATE` involves a time-intensive PostGIS query and thus the stakes are high.

30 or so minutes into the `UPDATE`, it exits due to an exception and I lose everything.  I both anticipate that exceptions will occur, and don't care if their data is lost.  Is there anyway to ignore these exceptions?

Comment: you can put `UPDATE` inside `DO` and add exception handling

Comment: There is no way to ignore that error. The UPDATE runs inside a transaction and by definition everything must succeed or nothing.

Comment: What kind of exception do you get?